# Problem calling npgsql stored function of a postgresql 10.10 database with postgis from EF Core 3.0

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I have a function with a input json parameter in text format, I do the casting to json inside itself. This function returns another Json in text format. When I call this function from PGAdmin 4 using another function test, it works fine, but if I call that function from EF Core 3.0 I get this error:

```
Error Name: invalid input syntax for type json  
Error State: 22P02  
Error Context: JSON data, line 1: {"ErrorMsg":"Error Name: type "geometry...  
PL/pgSQL function miguel.searchjson(text) line 87 at assignment  
SQL statement "SELECT * from miguel.searchJSON(param)"
PL/pgSQL function miguel.test_searchjson() line 19 at SQL statement
```

With other functions without Json that returns a text, I don't have problems in the execution. 
I am calling to my function that way:

```
var res = _context.JSResultSearch.FromSqlRaw("SELECT miguel.test_searchjson() as jsresult");
```

Frankly, I'm already desperate with this topic. I will be grateful with any help.

Comment: The error seems to be missing from your post.

Comment: Sorry, i had to edit several times. I had problems with the code format.

Comment: I have discovered that the problem is in the using of geometry and its operations. If I quit the geometry variable (geom) and the if of wkt conversion in miguel.SearchSum. The calling works fine. But I need to do the intersection with geometries. So I follow needing a solve. Thanks.

Comment: I have already found the problem. *The connection login used in EF Core didn't have permission on postgis schema.* The error is very confusing, It is enough with giving grant to login in that schema. So It already works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to call a function which returns a simple text, and expect EF Core to read it out for you (although this isn't clear, since you're calling FromSqlRaw on JSResultSearch, and we don't know what that is). EF Core doesn't support loading simple, non-entity values for you - see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11624.

However, EF Core wouldn't have much value here beyond simply dropping down to ADO.NET or using Dapper.

Comment: JSResultSearch is a class with an only property of string type called jsresult. There it is received the text return of the function postgresql. Actually the error is returned from postgresql function.